# Обращение к полю структуры

Tags: c

Есть массив структур, который я хочу отсортировать по значению конкретных полей. Имя поля может быть любым. Типы данных в полях идентичны, по этому хочу узнать, можно ли реализовать "переименование поля" (я понятия не имею, как это называется и существует ли вообще, так что не судите строго)
В общем, как я это себе представляю:

```cpp
            #include<string.h>
            typedef struct {
            int id;
            int year;
            int price;
            } example_struct;
        void(example_struct a[5], const char* usr_field){
            //вот здесь чисто плоды моей фантазии, чтобы передать смысл того, что мне нужно
            example_struct buff;
            [???] field_name;//какой то тип/указатель
            if(strcmp(usr_field, "id") == 0||strcmp(usr_field, "year") == 0||strcmp(usr_field, "price") == 0) field_name = usr_field;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5 - i; j++) {
                    if (a[j].field_name > a[j + 1].field_name) {
                        buff = a[j];
                        a[j] = a[j+1];
                        a[j+1] = buff;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int main {
            example_struct a[5];
            fill_arr(a);//как-то заполняет масив
            sort_arr(a,"year");
        }
```

Всё ради того, чтобы не писать отдельную сортировку для каждого поля.

Comment: Так С или C++??? Доступные решения в этих языках различаются критически.

Comment: Скорее для С.....

Comment: Почему тогда на вопросе болтается тэг [C++]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В примере, где все поля структуры имеют один и тот же тип - `int` - можно "выкрутиться" через использование указателей-на-члены. Ваша функция сортировки будет в таком случае будет объявлена как

```
void(example_struct a[5], int example_struct::*field)
```

а доступ к полю вы везде должны будете делать как

```
a[i].*field
```

Например

```
if (a[j].*field > a[j + 1].*field)
```

Тогда вы сможете вызывать вашу функцию как

```
sort_arr(a, &example_struct::id);
sort_arr(a, &example_struct::year);
sort_arr(a, &example_struct::price);
```

и получать сортировки по разным полям.

Разумеется, при желании вы можете реализовать этот подход так, как вы изначально хотели: через передачу в функцию строкового *имени* поля с объявлением указателя

```
int example_struct::*field = nullptr;
```

внутри функции и последующим

```
if (strcmp(usr_field, "id") == 0)
  field = &example_struct::id;
else if (strcmp(usr_field, "year") == 0)
  field = &example_struct::year;
else if (strcmp(usr_field, "price") == 0)
  field = &example_struct::price;
```

Такие указатели-на-члены не составит труда "сэмулировать" и в С коде, хотя синтаксис получится более громоздким.

---

Однако как только возникнет необходимость выполнять сортировку по полям разного типа, применить такой подход можно будет только через шаблоны

```
 template <typename T>
 void(example_struct a[5], T example_struct::*field)
```

что может быть чересчур расточительным и недостаточно гибким. Подход с использованием внешнего функтора-компаратора, вроде преложенного @AlexGlebe, намного более гибок.

Comment: А можно подробнее о том, как сэмулировать эти указатели-на-члены на С? И почему тип данного указателя int?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте однотипные функции для сравнения структур. А дальше передавайте адрес функции в `sort_arr`.

```
typedef bool ( * ExampleStructLess ) ( example_struct const * ,
  example_struct const * ) ;

bool ExampleStructLessById ( example_struct const * const a ,
  example_struct const * const b ) { return a->id < b->id; }

bool ExampleStructLessByYear ( example_struct const * const a ,
  example_struct const * const b ) { return a->year < b->year; }

void sort_arr ( example_struct * a , ExampleStructLess funcless ) {
  example_struct * x ;
  example_struct * y ;
  ...
  if ( funcless (  x ,  y ) ) ...
  ...
  }

sort_arr (a,ExampleStructLessById);
sort_arr (a,ExampleStructLessByYear);
```